# QRCode decoding in java without using any libraries

Tags: java, qr-code

I've been searching on how to scan a `QRCode` from `BufferedImage` in Java without using ZXing or any other libraries. That must be my own decoder. I'm searching for the simplest way to do this.

Does anybody know of any examples or know how to do this easily? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good luck. The whole project has evidently included 46 person-years of effort: http://www.ohloh.net/p/zxing/estimated_cost  Now, maybe 30% of that is Java, and 20% of that is QR codes, but that's still over 3 years of effort to write. That sounds kind of right -- I wrote it. I imagine you can cobble together a much less complete version in 6 months, but, wow are you sure you want to?

Comment: I didn't know that this is such complicated. A few days ago I've made my own 1D barcode decoder/encoder and it was not so difficult. And I thought that, qrcode is not so difficult to. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: It's many times more complicated, just in decoding (let alone detection). two types of error correction, masking, interleaving, segments, modes, etc before you even get the data. You might count the lines of code in zxing that decode UPC vs QR to get a sense of relative effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't support scanning of QR codes out-of-the-box. If you don't want to employ a library, you will have to write the whole mess yourself. That means you will have to scan through your image pixel by pixel and determine what the image looks like and what it means.

Answer (score 1):

As @Till Helge Viking mentions, it is not included in the standard java libraries, so you would have to implement the encoding and decoding by yourself. [This information](http://www.swetake.com/qr/qr1_en.html) might be of use to you.